# Can I response file Node to React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest

Is it possible to create a rest api responsing an image file using `node`? Wondering if there is a proper way to do this.

I have studying fs module to find something.

Comment: Take a look here: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/

Answer (score 0):

you can do it

```
var fs = require('fs'),


 fs.readFile(__dirname + req.url, function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
      return;
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
```

For more details see [here](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/)

Comment: hi, i use the fs readFile method and i response the data like this

res.json({file:data})

Im getting buffer and learning how to make it viewable

Comment: @AvocadoFruit
witch type of the file that wants to send?

Comment: png, Buffer.from(data.file.data).toString() i use something like this when i receive the response back

Comment: well i wish other file type will do

Comment: i receive somethin like diamond with question marks AHHAHA its really hard to describe what it is

Comment: try such  var img = Buffer.from(base64Data, 'base64');

Comment: @AvocadoFruit first of all, check it with a text file

Comment: text file? i practice to show a text file?

Comment: text fie or png file?